# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory. Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04

My script is on a server running ubuntu 16.04. I want this script to collect some results in the csv file.
for this I:

```
with open('./folder/tickets.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as ouf:
    for i in d:
        i = str(i)
        ouf.write(i + '\n')
```

as a result, I get an error: 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './folder/tickets.csv'

I tried to specify the absolute path (/home/root/folder/tickets.csv), but the error is still the same

tell me what is wrong?

Comment: First things first: are you _absolutely sure_ that you are indeed running this script on your server, and not locally? Are you absolutely sure that this file is located on the server, and not on your local machine? If you want the script on your server to access data on your local machine, merely `open`ing it won't work.

Comment: Is absolute path `/home/root/folder/tickets.csv`, not just a `/root/folder/tickets.csv`? As far as I know, there's no `/home/root` on ubuntu, just `/root`

Comment: @ForceBru Yes, I am sure that I perform all operations on my server, and not locally. I'm not trying to access a local file from outside

Comment: @Mikhail Stepanov also fails

Comment: @MikhailStepanov the same you were right /root/folder

Answer (score 0):

the question is closed. having tried the path again '/root/folder' everything worked